# How would I format Zend_Form_Element_Radio so the label comes after the input

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have been trying to implement the solution in an earlier version of this question at:

[How would I format Zend_Form_Element_Radio so the label follows the input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640656/how-would-i-format-zend-form-element-radio-so-the-label-follows-the-input)

By creating an extended helper `MyLib_View_Helper_FormRadio` but must be missing something obvious with this!

My question is how do I get `Zend_Form_Element_Radio()` to use this now instead of the version of the helper in `Zend_View_Helper_FormRadio`?

I thought initially that this was done by creating the element with

```
$radio = new MyLib_View_Helper_FormRadio();
```

but realised its not.

Changing the way the label and input are ordered in the `Zend_View_Helper_FormRadio.php` does the trick but I realise that the Zend files should not be altered.

If anyone can help me with t his I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

In your `MyLib_View_Helper_FormRadio` class, you have a method, like this (it's an example):

```
public function formRadioCustom($name, $value = null, $attribs = null,
    $options = null, $listsep = "<br />\n"){...}
```

So to call it instead of `formRadio` of `Zend_View_Helper_FormRadio`, if I'm not mistaken, you have to do:

```
 $element->addDecorators(array(array('ViewHelper',array('helper' => 'formRadioCustom'))));
```

And in your bootstrap add a method to add helper like this:

```
protected function _initViewHelpers() {
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->->addHelperPath('MyLib/View/Helper/', 'MyLib_View_Helper');
}
```